# String cannot contain embedded nulls?

Tags: c#

Just looking at the docs for [ModuleBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywdse26t.aspx) and it's method [DefineType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f53tx4x8.aspx) which takes a string amongst other parameters.

In the write up it states the parameter 'cannot contain embedded nulls'.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example of a string with an embedded null is:

```
var example = "This is a null: \0";
```

`'\0'` is the [Unicode character 'NULL' (U+0000)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

A string is not null terminated (ends on a null) so therefore you can actually store null characters ('\0') inside of a string.  The string you are going to work with cannot have one of these special characters inside it.

Here is Microsoft's definition of string in reference to null characters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx

Comment: Actually in practice a string in .NET is *both* length-prefixed *and* null terminated. The same is true in OLE Automation; BSTRs also have this property.

Comment: @Eric Lippert - from the Microsoft documentation `There is no null-terminating character at the end of a C# string`

Comment: There is no null terminating character there from the perspective of the C# user; if you have a ten-character string and ask for the 10th character, you don't get a null. But as an implementation detail, the framework actually does allocate an extra two bytes and actually does put a zero char in there. Similarly, as an implementation detail the runtime stores the length of the string in the memory before the character data. There's no way for you to know that *in C#*, but if you took a look at the raw memory in a debugger you'd see it.

Comment: @Eric Lippert - Interesting.  I learn something new every day.